# Can I show a fallback ad if my adsense for search unit is empty?

Tags: adsense

We've just added [adsense for search](https://code.google.com/apis/custom-search-ads/) to our site.  We have three units on the page, and sometimes there aren't enough ads to fill all three, so they end up empty.  When this happens, we'd like to show some alternative content.  Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

There is a possiblity to have a fallback defined:
http://webdevblogger.de/allgemein/google-adsense-snippet-p17.html

Answer (score 1):

AdSense dashboard where you setup up the ad lets you setup a fallback url or image.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a bit of jQuery javascript. Assuming the ads place some sort of element inside a container:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($("#containerId").children().length == 0) 
        { $("#containerId").append("<img src='fallbackad.jpg' />") }
})
```

Comment: The ads are placed in an iframe which loads a page from a different domain, so security restrictions prevent us from examining its contents.